# How to resolve the error ''function' object has no attribute 'form'' in Flask python?

Tags: forms, flask, attributes

I have no idea what this error means:

```
selected = request.form.get('industry')
```

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'form'

Can anyone help?

Comment: in your routes.py: add form = ClassName().

Answer (score 1):

You have defined or imported a function called "request". For example by importing all attributes from a module that contains a function named "request": "from module1 import *". This shadows the request from Flask.

Comment: Thank you bro I jt found out where did it gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

You've imported the wrong `request`.

I suppose that you might have imported an `request` previously defined as a function from other packages and shadows `flask.request`. That's wrong.

What you should do is to import request from `flask` through the following command:

```
from flask import request
```

Comment: Yup, I imported request instead thank you for your support